# How to create a dynamic/flexible file/folder path in HTML?

Tags: html, dynamic

I have an HTML code that displays a link to a PDF file. When you click on the link, a link to an online sharepoint folder opens. Unfortunately the PDF file is named according to the current year and week and therefore dynamic. I would like to change the current "fixed" HTML code for taking a specific PDF from an online sharepoint based on the last Calendar Week. This would be an example of the current fixed code line:

```
<a href="https://sharepoint.com/MyFolder/Example_2020_WK10.pdf" target="content" title="Updated for for previous week">Update</a>
```

For example, if we're in calendar week 11 in 2020, it should take the PDF of week 10 as shown above. If we're in calendar week 12 in 2020, it should take the PDF "Example_2020_WK11.pdf" and so on.

How can I make the PDF name flexible/dynamic based on the current week (-1) and current year?

(I'm a newbie in HTML, so grateful for any help. Many thanks!)

Comment: Static HTML is not enough in this case. You need to use JavaScript to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static HTML is not enough here. You need to use JavaScript.

You can create a function as follows.

```
function weekOfYear() {
    let now = new Date();
    return Math.round((now - new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
}
```

Note however that this function returns '0' for first week of the year.

Check example [here](https://codepen.io/ahmadshahwan/pen/ExyxBJX).

The example is only meant to illustrate how it can be done. Note that in real life you are better off having the script in a separate file (as show [here](https://codepen.io/ahmadshahwan/pen/BazagXg)).

Comment: Thank you very much, Ahmad! Exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly for changing the week number.

Do you know how to adjust your Java Script code to also automatically update the Year number when changing e.g. to 2021?

Comment: Another question would be, if I take your code line 6 and add a -5 after the brackets to show the week number of 5 weeks ago and we are in CW3 in 2021, how can I make sure to still show CW50 of 2020? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: To return the weekend number "slid" over last year use the modulus operator like so: `weekOfYear = (52 + weekOfYear) % 52`. 52 being the number of weeks in a year. To decide if you have to subtract one of the year number, check if the original weekOfYear is strictly negative.